# Retriving price from a page

Tags: google-sheets, xpath, google-sheets-formula, xpath-2.0

I am trying to retrive the price from a custom search [Page](https://starcitygames.com/search/?hawksearchable=card_nametext%3A%20%22Decree%20of%20Annihilation%22%20AND%20search_includetext%3A%20%22default%22&language=English&filter_set=Scourge&finish=Non-foil) in google sheets using importxml() but i have an empty result error

```
=IMPORTXML("https://starcitygames.com/search/?hawksearchable=card_nametext%3A+%22Shaman%20of%20the%20Great%20Hunt%22+AND+search_includetext%3A+%22default%22&language=English&filter_set=Fate%20Reforged&finish=Non-foil","/html/body/div/div[1]/main/main/div[7]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]")
```

[Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWbGi.png)

[This is an example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B2Ov6zhUYaZ-uYrTShvvuQG5jYPMv-Udf-t_2Xx6tcI/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/QMhgq3v.gif

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the results in that HTML page are generated in your browser using JavaScript. Google Sheets does not run JavaScript so it never sees the HTML that you see in the browser. See https://www.reddit.com/r/googlesheets/wiki/import-html-xml/ for more information and a possible way forward.